# I have php script, but have to to run in Js. How?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension

I have a php script i am good in php but js starving me. and i need to use this little php script in every page via chrome extension using content scripts but how can i put these php fuctions in .js file, or how we write this script in js?? bit confused any body can help in this, I'll be very thankful.

```
<?php$homepage = file_get_contents('http://example.com/content.php');echo $homepage;?>
```

Comment: Browsers don't have a built-in PHP interpreter so adding this code is meaningless.

Comment: can you help to write this code in js ?

Comment: The goal you're trying to achieve in the end is not obvious from your description. If you want to add HTML from that URL into every page, you can simply download it via XHR/fetch once, store in chrome.storage.local, then your content script can read it and add to the page.

Comment: @Damon The [official Content Scripts lading page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) states: `"Content scripts are JavaScript files that run in the context of web pages."` Without a PHP interpreter in-browser, I'm afraid you wouldn't  find much success with PHP in your content script. As wOxxOm has suggested, you may want to look into making a POST for the data you're looking for. I'd recommend breaking that to a separate question with the appropriate tags.

Comment: You can use `content.js` to then add/inject a script tag into the dom. Then just distribute it with your extension. Not a good idea to do remote stuff, in case your server or vcs get tampered with.

Comment: I think it'll help please elaborate more or any tutorial or link is more appreciated Thanks. @wOxxOm

Comment: See how others do it, https://github.com/xd4rker/MinerBlock/blob/master/js/content.js

Comment: Basically i want to add html from that url @wOxxOm is right. but the content will change on every session and for every user . so that's why i want to trigger it from back-end, so i can change data when i want to.

Comment: you could use ajax to load the page and display on the html element.

Comment: @Damon you can pull `HTML` from server easily using `AJAX` but you want the html to change for each user session. What is your plan to serve a separate html for each user?

Answer (score 0):

I think that dynamic script loading suits you

I your PHP/JS File (readPage.js.php)

```
<?php
    $homepage = file_get_contents('http://example.com/content.php');
    $homepage = str_replace('"', '\"', $homepage);//Escaping double quotes
    echo "const homepage = \"$homepage\";";//Javascript constant declaration
?>
```

Then, in your HTML file, add

```
<script>
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function(){
    alert(homepage);
}
script.src = "readPage.js.php";
</script>
```